# How to access the read buffer of tokio::io::BufStream?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I recognized that `tokio::io::BufReader` has a `buffer()` method for accessing its internal read buffer. However I cannot find such an interface for `tokio::io::BufStream`, nor can I access the internal `BufReader` of a `BufStream` by using the public API.

I wonder if this is by design, or if there is some other way to do it?

BTW, the following is my use case:

I want to implement a traffic dispatcher for a socket with the trait `AsyncRead + AsyncWrite`. The dispatcher will try to peek the first read of the underlying socket to determine where the traffic will be routed, and then return a `BufStream` that also supports `AsyncRead + AsyncWrite`, as if the original socket is untouched (no data consumed).
My plan is to first trigger a `fill_buf()` call to the `BufStream`, then to look at the internal read buffer (which I don't how to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an inherent limitation: [`BufStream` is just `BufReader<BufWriter<RW>>`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.17.0/src/tokio/io/util/buf_stream.rs.html#21). You can do it yourself if you need and then you can access the buffers, but there is no need to: `fill_buf()` returns the filled buffer, so you can just use its returned value.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that `fill_buf()` will return the buffer earlier.